# pg_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($result)

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-8

Actualmente estoy creando una vista en blade para la totalización de reportes por región. estoy utilizando el `while` para la totalización dentro de postgresql. mi código es el siguiente

```php
public function Totales()
    {

        $total = DB::table('filtro_reporte')
        ->select('nom_acueducto')
        ->get();

            $caracas = 0;
            $miranda1 = 0;
            $vargas = 0;
            $miranda2 = 0;
            $miranda3 = 0;
            $mirada4 = 0;

        while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)){
            $caracas+=$row['Metropolitano'];
            $miranda1+=$row['Barlovento'];
            $vargas+=$row['Vargas'];
            $miranda2+=$row['Altos Mirandinos'];
            $miranda3+=$row['Guarenas, Guatire'];
            $mirada4+=$row['Valles del Tuy'];
            }
        }
```

Lo cual me arroja el error de:

> pg_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type resource, Illuminate\Support\Collection given

Ocurre al intentar ejecutar el `while`, de que manera se estructuraría para su funcionamiento?

Comment: Y que contiene $result ??

Comment: pasanos un `dd($result)`, incluyelo en e lpost

Comment: El dd($result); si extrae los datos que quiero de la db 

Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1457 ▼
  #items: array:8 [▼
    0 => {#1459 ▶}
    1 => {#1461 ▶}
    2 => {#1462 ▶}
    3 => {#1463 ▶}
    4 => {#1464 ▶}
    5 => {#1465 ▶}
    6 => {#1466 ▶}
    7 => {#1467 ▶}
  ]
}

Comment: No entiendo mucho lo que intentas hacer aquí. El mensaje de error te está diciendo claramente que `$result` es [una colección de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections). Es un objeto con todo lo necesario para leerlo, mostrarlo, extraerlo, particionarlo o lo que sea. ¿Por qué intentas leer `$result` como si estuvieras en contexto de PostgreSQL? Tú no obtuviste `$result` con la API de PostgreSQL..., no puedes por tanto leerlo con métodos de esa API.